# Como usar If com Insert em MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma variável x, e quero verificar o valor dela com um if, e caso o valor seja acima de 10 (por exemplo) eu quero realizar um insert numa tabela, caso contrário um select nela.

É algo relativamente simples, mas não consigo achar porque na maioria dos fóruns as pessoas enfeitam tanto os códigos que acabo me perdendo. Quero algo direto.

Comment: Já tentou ir direto no site do MySQL?: [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html)

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se é a solução ideal.
Também não sei se é a forma correta.
Mas por título de curiosidade e estudo (pra mim e pra todos), dê uma olhada nessa `Function`.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION SimpleCompare(n INT)
  RETURNS VARCHAR(500)

  BEGIN
    DECLARE s VARCHAR(500);

    IF n <= 10 THEN insert into tabela(campo) values(FLOOR(RAND()*10)); SET s = 'INSERIDO';
    ELSE select GROUP_CONCAT(campo) from tabela into s;
    END IF;

    RETURN s;
  END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Chamando-a assim:

```
select SimpleCompare(8);
select SimpleCompare(11);
```

Em PHP é um pouco mais simples, mas como não indicou nenhuma linguagem não sei se está usando alguma.

```
if($x>10){
   $sql = "insert into tabela(campos) values(valores)";
}else{
   $sql = "select campos from tabela";
}
```

Comment: É `function` e não `procedure`. Outra solução para o `select` é criar um `cursor` e fazer uma iteração nele caso necessite algo mais complexo.

Comment: Function, Editado ;)